# Finding the minimum $P(X_i>X_j)$ for all $i\neq j$?

Tags: probability, inequality, order-statistics, elementary-probability

I came across this probability question today:

> Let $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ be discrete random variables. Denote $a_{ij}=\mathbb{P}(X_i>X_j)$, show that $\text{min}\{a_{12},a_{23},a_{31}\}\leq\frac23$.

I’m not sure where to begin — is this an order statistics question? My intuition is that this is similar to the stick breaking problem, although I doubt this is of use since they are discrete random variables. Additionally, is there a generalisation for $n$ variables? Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume the converse, that the min is strictly greater than $2/3$

Then $P(X_1 > X_3) \ge P(X_1 >X_2 > X_3) >1/3$, which is absurd given that $P(X_3 > X_1) >2/3$ by assumption.

To see the  lower bound on $P(X_1 >X_2 > X_3)$, observe that 
\begin{align*}P(X_1 > X_2 >X_3)&
 =P(\{X_1 > X_2\} \cap \{X_2>X_3\}) \\
&=  P(X_1 > X_2)+P(X_2>X_3)-P(\{X_1 > X_2\} \cup \{X_2>X_3\}) \\
& > 4/3-1=1/3\end{align*}

As for the generalisation to $n$ events, it will be the same statement with $(n-1)/(n)$ replacing $2/3$.

Comment: Use \{ and \} for curly braces.

Comment: For your second paragraph do you assume WLOG that P(X3>X1) is the smallest?

Comment: No I don't.  (Only assumption : min>2/3). Perhaps the best to understand this kind of exercises is to draw a figure with the events at stake (potatoes or Venn diagrams), and look at their intersections.